# Трудоемкое формирование Excel через Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi, poi

Всем привет, столкнулся с проблемой, при формирование эксель файла, процесс с каждой итерацией начинает тормозить, первые итерации проходят за 60-70мс, последующие увеличиваются на 10-20мс, к 50й итерации уже больше секунды.

каждая итерация состоит из добавления от 6 до 10 строк, с применениями стилей, форматирования, объединения. То есть формируется отчет.

общее число итераций может достигать до 800 итераций.

Может кто подскажет, кто-то может решал такую проблему? по другому не могу формировать отчет. Может как-то через многопоточность возможно? Но я к сожалению в ней пока сырой.

Вот кусок основного кода, кода много.

```
      try (BufferedInputStream fis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileCalc))) {

            ZipSecureFile.setMinInflateRatio(-1.0d);
            xssfWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
            XSSFSheet sheet = xssfWorkbook.getSheetAt(0);

            // Строка старта шапки
            int rowStartHead = 0;
            int numberTable = 1;
            for (TotalModel totalModel: listTotalModel) {
                if (totalModel != null) {

                    // Строка финиша шапки
                    int rowFinishHead = rowStartHead + 3;

                    for (int i = rowStartHead; i <= rowFinishHead; i++) {
                        XSSFRow rowHead = sheet.createRow(i);
                        Cell head0 = rowHead.createCell(0);
                        head0.setCellValue("№п/п");
                        head0.setCellStyle(cellStyleHead(sheet));

                        Cell head1 = rowHead.createCell(1);
                        head1.setCellValue("Станция отправления");
                        head1.setCellStyle(cellStyleHead(sheet));

                        Cell head2 = rowHead.createCell(2);
                        head2.setCellValue("Дорога отпр.");
                        head2.setCellStyle(cellStyleHead(sheet));
                        sheet.setColumnWidth(2, 2194);

                        Cell head3 = rowHead.createCell(3);
                        head3.setCellValue("Станция назначения");
                        head3.setCellStyle(cellStyleHead(sheet));

                        Cell head4 = rowHead.createCell(4);
                        head4.setCellValue("Дорога назн.");
                        head4.setCellStyle(cellStyleHead(sheet));
                        sheet.setColumnWidth(4, 2194);

                        Cell head5 = rowHead.createCell(5);
                        head5.setCellValue("Наименование груза");
                        head5.setCellStyle(cellStyleHead(sheet));

                        Cell head6 = rowHead.createCell(6);
                        head6.setCellValue("Расст., км");
                        head6.setCellStyle(cellStyleHead(sheet));

                        Cell head7 = rowHead.createCell(7);
                        head7.setCellValue("Время в пути, сут");
                        head7.setCellStyle(cellStyleHead(sheet));

                        Cell head8 = rowHead.createCell(8);
                        head8.setCellValue("Погр. / выгр.");
                        head8.setCellStyle(cellStyleHead(sheet));

                        Cell head9 = rowHead.createCell(9);
                        head9.setCellValue("Оборот, сут.");
                        head9.setCellStyle(cellStyleHead(sheet));

                        Cell head10 = rowHead.createCell(10);
                        head10.setCellValue("ВО");
                        head10.setCellStyle(cellStyleHead(sheet));

                        Cell head11 = rowHead.createCell(11);
                        if (i == rowFinishHead) {
                            head11.setCellValue("руб/ваг.");
                        } else {
                            head11.setCellValue("ДОХОД");
                        }
                        head11.setCellStyle(cellStyleHeadBottom(sheet));

                        Cell head12 = rowHead.createCell(12);
                        if (i == rowFinishHead - 1 || i == rowFinishHead - 2) {
                            head12.setCellValue("Тариф в собств. вагонах");
                        } else if (i == rowFinishHead) {
                            head12.setCellValue("руб/ваг.");
                        } else {
                            head12.setCellValue("РАСХОД");
                        }
                        head12.setCellStyle(cellStyleHeadBottom(sheet));

                        Cell head13 = rowHead.createCell(13);
                        if (i == rowFinishHead - 1 || i == rowFinishHead - 2) {
                            head13.setCellValue("За нахождение в пути");
                        } else if (i == rowFinishHead) {
                            head13.setCellValue("руб/ваг.");
                        } else {
                            head13.setCellValue("ПРИБЫЛЬ");
                        }
                        head13.setCellStyle(cellStyleHeadBottom(sheet));

                        Cell head14 = rowHead.createCell(14);
                        if (i == rowFinishHead - 1 || i == rowFinishHead - 2) {
                            head14.setCellValue("В сутки");
                        } else if (i == rowFinishHead) {
                            head14.setCellValue("руб/ваг/сут.");
                        } else {
                            head14.setCellValue("ПРИБЫЛЬ");
                        }
                        head14.setCellStyle(cellStyleHeadRight(sheet));
                    }

                    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
                        sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(rowStartHead, rowFinishHead, i, i));
                    }
                    sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(rowStartHead, rowFinishHead - 1, 11, 11));
                    sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(rowStartHead, rowStartHead, 13, 14));
                    for (int i = 12; i < 15; i++) {
                        sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(rowStartHead + 1, rowFinishHead - 1, i, i));
                    }

                    // Строка первого рейса
                    int rowFirstRoute = rowFinishHead + 1;
                    // Номер первой ячейки данных
                    int firstNumberCell = rowFirstRoute + 1;
                    boolean isMarker = false;

                    for (Route route : totalModel.getTotalList()) {

                        int num = rowFirstRoute + 1;
                        XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(rowFirstRoute);
                        Cell number = row.createCell(0);
                        if (!isMarker) {
                            number.setCellValue(numberTable);
                            isMarker = true;
                        } else {
                            number.setCellValue("");
                        }
                        number.setCellStyle(cellStyleField(sheet));

                        Cell stationDeparture = row.createCell(1);
                        stationDeparture.setCellValue(route.getStationDeparture().getNameStation());
                        if (route.isFlagNeedCalc()) {
                            stationDeparture.setCellStyle(cellStyleFieldNeedCalc(sheet,false));
                        } else {
                            stationDeparture.setCellStyle(cellStyleField(sheet));
                        }

                        Cell roadDeparture = row.createCell(2);
                        roadDeparture.setCellValue(route.getStationDeparture().getRoad().getNameRoad());
                        if (route.isFlagNeedCalc()) {
                            roadDeparture.setCellStyle(cellStyleFieldNeedCalc(sheet,false));
                        } else {
                            roadDeparture.setCellStyle(cellStyleField(sheet));
                        }

                        Cell stationDestination = row.createCell(3);
                        stationDestination.setCellValue(route.getStationDestination().getNameStation());
                        if (route.isFlagNeedCalc()) {
                            stationDestination.setCellStyle(cellStyleFieldNeedCalc(sheet,false));
                        } else {
                            stationDestination.setCellStyle(cellStyleField(sheet));
                        }

                        Cell roadDestination = row.createCell(4);
                        roadDestination.setCellValue(route.getStationDestination().getRoad().getNameRoad());
                        if (route.isFlagNeedCalc()) {
                            roadDestination.setCellStyle(cellStyleFieldNeedCalc(sheet,false));
                        } else {
                            roadDestination.setCellStyle(cellStyleField(sheet));
                        }

                        Cell cargo = row.createCell(5);
                        if (route.getRate() != 0) {
                            cargo.setCellValue(route.getCargo().getNameCargo());
                            cargo.setCellStyle(cellStyleFieldCargo(sheet));
                        } else {
                            cargo.setCellValue("Порожняк");
                            cargo.setCellStyle(cellStyleFieldCargo(sheet));
                        }

                        Cell distance = row.createCell(6);
                        distance.setCellValue(route.getDistance());
                        distance.setCellStyle(cellStyleFieldFormat(sheet, true));

                        Cell countDays = row.createCell(7);
                        countDays.setCellValue(route.getCountDays());
                        countDays.setCellStyle(cellStyleField(sheet));

                        Cell daysLoadUnload = row.createCell(8);
                        daysLoadUnload.setCellValue(route.getCountDaysLoadAndUnload());
                        daysLoadUnload.setCellStyle(cellStyleField(sheet));

                        Cell fullCountDays = row.createCell(9);
                        fullCountDays.setCellFormula("SUM(H" + num + ":I" + num + ")");
                        fullCountDays.setCellStyle(cellStyleField(sheet));

                        Cell call9 = row.createCell(10);
                        call9.setCellValue("поваг");
                        call9.setCellStyle(cellStyleField(sheet));
                        sheet.autoSizeColumn(10);

                        Cell rate = row.createCell(11);
                        if (route.getRate() == 0) {
                            rate.setCellStyle(cellStyleFieldNull(sheet));
                        } else {
                            rate.setCellValue(route.getRate());
                            if (route.isFlagNeedCalc()) {
                                rate.setCellStyle(cellStyleFieldNeedCalc(sheet, false));
                            } else {
                                rate.setCellStyle(cellStyleFieldFormat(sheet, false));
                            }
                        }

                        Cell tariff = row.createCell(12);
                        if (route.getTariff() == 0) {
                            tariff.setCellStyle(cellStyleFieldNull(sheet));
                        } else {
                            tariff.setCellValue(route.getTariff());
                            tariff.setCellStyle(cellStyleFieldFormat(sheet, false));
                        }

                        Cell rateTariff = row.createCell(13);
                        rateTariff.setCellFormula("L" + num + "-M" + num);
                        rateTariff.setCellStyle(cellStyleFieldFormat(sheet, false));
                        sheet.setColumnWidth(13, 3182);

                        Cell cell13 = row.createCell(14);
                        cell13.setCellValue("");
                        cell13.setCellStyle(cellStyleFieldRightBold(sheet));

                        rowFirstRoute++;
                    }

                    // Номер последней ячейки данных
                    int lastNumberCell = rowFirstRoute;
                    int totalYieldNum = rowFirstRoute + 1;
                    XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(rowFirstRoute);

                    Cell cell0 = row.createCell(0);
                    cell0.setCellStyle(cellStyleFieldTotal(sheet));

                    Cell cell1 = row.createCell(1);
                    cell1.setCellStyle(cellStyleFieldTotal(sheet));

                    Cell cell2 = row.createCell(2);
                    cell2.setCellStyle(cellStyleFieldTotal(sheet));

                    Cell cell3 = row.createCell(3);
                    cell3.setCellStyle(cellStyleFieldTotal(sheet));

                    Cell cell4 = row.createCell(4);
                    cell4.setCellStyle(cellStyleFieldTotal(sheet));

                    Cell cell5 = row.createCell(5);
                    cell5.setCellStyle(cellStyleFieldTotal(sheet));

                    sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(rowFirstRoute, rowFirstRoute, 0, 5));
                    // Строка итоговых расчетов
                    Cell totalDistance = row.createCell(6);
                    totalDistance.setCellFormula("SUM(G" + firstNumberCell + ":G" + lastNumberCell + ")");
                    totalDistance.setCellStyle(cellStyleFieldTotalFormat(sheet, true));

                    Cell totalCountDays = row.createCell(7);
                    totalCountDays.setCellFormula("SUM(H" + firstNumberCell + ":H" + lastNumberCell + ")");
                    totalCountDays.setCellStyle(cellStyleFieldTotal(sheet));

                    Cell totalCountLoadUnloadDays = row.createCell(8);
                    totalCountLoadUnloadDays.setCellFormula("SUM(I" + firstNumberCell + ":I" + lastNumberCell + ")");
                    totalCountLoadUnloadDays.setCellStyle(cellStyleFieldTotal(sheet));

                    Cell totalFullCountDays = row.createCell(9);
                    totalFullCountDays.setCellFormula("SUM(J" + firstNumberCell + ":J" + lastNumberCell + ")");
                    totalFullCountDays.setCellStyle(cellStyleFieldTotal(sheet));

                    Cell cell10 = row.createCell(10);
                    cell10.setCellStyle(cellStyleFieldTotal(sheet));

                    Cell cell11 = row.createCell(11);
                    cell11.setCellStyle(cellStyleFieldTotal(sheet));

                    Cell cell12 = row.createCell(12);
                    cell12.setCellStyle(cellStyleFieldTotal(sheet));

                    Cell totalRateTariff = row.createCell(13);
                    totalRateTariff.setCellFormula("SUM(N" + firstNumberCell + ":N" + lastNumberCell + ")");
                    totalRateTariff.setCellStyle(cellStyleFieldTotalFormat(sheet,false));

                    Cell yield = row.createCell(14);
                    yield.setCellFormula("N" + totalYieldNum + "/J" + totalYieldNum);
                    yield.setCellStyle(cellStyleFieldTotalRight(sheet, false));
                    sheet.autoSizeColumn(14);

                    Cell cell15 = row.createCell(15);
                    cell15.setCellValue(totalModel.getYield());

                    Cell cell16 = row.createCell(16);
                    cell16.setCellFormula("P" + totalYieldNum + "-O" + totalYieldNum);

                    Cell cell17 = row.createCell(17);
                    cell17.setCellFormula("Q" + totalYieldNum + "*J" + totalYieldNum);

                    rowStartHead = lastNumberCell + 1;
                    numberTable++;
                }
            }
            xssfWorkbook.write(outputStream);
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
        }
```

Comment: Попробуйте закоментарить все что не касается вставки данных. Стили, фонты и тд. Замедление останется?

Comment: @Денис пробовал, чуть быстрее получается, но все равно. Мне кажется причина именно в том, что я делаю все это в одном методе. Я попробовал перенести все это в отдельный метод и вызывать его каждый раз, при этом я в этом методе открываю временный файл куда все записываю. Но теперь в сожаление постоянное перезапись файл приводит к перезагрузке томката.

Comment: про перезагрузку вспомнил, у меня параметр reloadable был включен, который отслеживает изменение в контексте и перезапускает приложение

Comment: @Денис сделал еще раз тестирование без стилей, и правда, время работы уменьшается в 100 раз. скорей всего это стили. Но жаль без них не могу. Думаю попробовать SXSSFWorkbook

Comment: правильно пишут, стили получайте 1 раз. Не торопитесь, продолжайте искать причину тормозов. Вы в начале пути;)

Comment: @Денис да вот кое что нашел, если объединения убрать, то время сокращается до 7 минут если 5000 строк) Но и без них не могу(

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте расчитать стиль `cellStyleField(sheet)` один раз и другие стили тоже и вынести это из цикла, потом подставляйте только значения.

Сейчас у вас конструкция такая:

```
    for (TotalModel totalModel: listTotalModel) { 
        //заполнение шапки
        for (int i = rowStartHead; i <= rowFinishHead; i++) {
             ...
             <cell>.setCellStyle(cellStyleHead(sheet));
             ...
        }  

        //заполнение данными
        for (Route route : totalModel.getTotalList()) {
             ...
             <cell>.setCellStyle(cellStyleField(sheet));
             ...

        }

    }
```

я предлагаю попробовать примерно такой подход:

```
style1 = ...
style2 = ...

header = buildHeader();

for (TotalModel totalModel: listTotalModel) { 
     setHeader(header );
     setData(sheet);
     setStyles(sheet);
}

private void buildHeader(XSSFSheet sheet){
   ...
}

private void setHeader(XSSFSheet sheet){
   ...
}

private void setData(XSSFSheet sheet){
   ...
}

private void setStyles(XSSFSheet sheet){
   <range1>.setCellStyle(style1);
   <range2>.setCellStyle(style2);
}
```

Так избавитесь от многочисленных заданий стилей на каждую ячейку, и будет проще разбираться в коде в будущем, когда попросят доработать отчет.

Comment: я вынес все стили в отдельные классы, и далее уже раз в начале инициализировал это класс CellStyleHead cellStyleHead = new CellStyleHead(xssfWorkbook); и далее уже при setCellStyle вызывал получение стиля .setCellStyle(cellStyleHead.getXssfCellStyle()); Но к сожалению, все равно время работы не ускорилось(((

Comment: я уже начал подумывать, может это проблема в методе setCellStyle

Comment: Правда ваш код немного не могу понять.

Comment: @Владислав, что именно не смогли понять? Смысл в том чтоб не присваивать стиль каждой ячейке во время заполнения листа данными. А в методе `setStyles( XSSFSheet sheet )` выделяйте нужные диапазоны и и присваивайте соответствующие стили.

Comment: Ага, теперь понял, но у меня проблема в том, что я не знаю изначально этот диапазон, у меня формирубтся таблицы, и каждой может быть от 2 до 10 строк плюс строка итога. Если только после каждой итерации totalmodel так делать.

Comment: По экспериментировал, убрал объединение, отработал на 100 итераций(600строк) - за 8 секунд, 797 итераций(5800 строк) - за 7 минут, в разы быстрее, но опять же, не могу от объединения отказаться(( В общем, это проблема в POI, в частности в setCellStyle ((

Comment: вы не могли бы подсказать, как бы можно реализовать вот вашей идеи методы setHeader() и buildHeader(). Я закомменил как раз получение шапки, и скорость работы увеличилась в разы, с 72 секунд до 3. Но как можно было бы эту шапку сделать отдельно и потом применять в определенные места?

Comment: Как вариант, можете шапку сделать на другом листе, и потом копировать в нужные места. Еще совет- чтобы вы не делали в методе `cellStyleHead()` и др. - сохраните стиль один раз в переменную и потом применяйте, сейчас так получается что вы для каждой ячейки новый стиль создаете. И еще по заполнению шапки, сейчас в цикле вы заполняете A1 = "№п/п", А2="№п/п", A3="№п/п", потом вы их объединяете и получаете то что вам нужно, но при работе у вас создаются лишние строки, которые вы лишний раз присваиваете ячейкам - можно еще здесь оптимизировать.

Comment: И еще, желательно номера колонок сделать в виде переменных, чтоб по именам было понятно что это, иначе в дальнейшем код будет трудно поддерживать. А отчеты, как правило, меняются достаточно часто.

Comment: Вот как раз из-за шапки все это накладно работает. Но я не могу понять именно механизм, как ее скопировать вот именно, например от ячейки А1 до ячейки Е4, чтобы со всеми стилями объединениями она легла в этот диапазон. Мне особо не приходилось работать с POI :( а сами стили я вынес в отдельный класс и при инициализации я создаю необходимые и уже потом геттером вызываю, но это не особо отразилось на времени работы к сожалению. Вот единственное нашел узкое место это объединения, если шапку с объединениями закомментит, и например добавлять 50записей(это окло 200 строк), то отрабатывает за 9секунд